# GPG disabling ssh support for an authentication key coming from a smartcard

Tags: gpg

When a gpg smartcard (e.g. yubikey) is inserted and contains an authentication key, the key is automatically enrolled by the gpg-agent.  That means the key is usable for any ssh operation without needing to add its keygrip inside the file ~/.gnupg/sshcontrol.

Source: [Agent-Configuration](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Configuration.html) documentation (look after the last line of text inside the sshcontrol paragraph)

On a specific computer I would like to disable this default behavior without disabling other features provided by the smartcard.  I was hoping to be able to disable the authentication key by prepending a '!' to its keygrip inside the sshcontrol file as described into the [Agent-Configuration](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Configuration.html) documentation (look after the before last line of text inside the sshcontrol paragraph) e.g:

```
!BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 0
```

But it does not work. 
With BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB being the keygrip of the authentication key.

Not related to disabling a key, I also tried to enable the confirm flag for the authentication key coming from the smartcard:

```
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB 0 confirm
```

And it does not work either.  I am really wondering if the gpg-agent reads the sshcontrol information for smartcard keys.

Settings of my infrastructure:

- GnuPG version 2.2.12
- only RSA 4096 bits keys

Comment: Have you tried reloading GPG agent ie: `gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye` ? See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Reload_the_agent

Comment: I've just tried to be sure.  Still the same behavior.  In any other cases, gpg-agent reads sshcontrol file again at every ssh query it receives, it would have be strange to need to restart it to take sshcontrol changes into account.